# How do I return local data with a recursive function in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to write a recursive algorithm in Rust. With the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Error {
    Bad,
    ReallyBad,
}

fn expand_symbols<'a, T: AsRef<str>>(
    symbols: &'a [T],
    ops: &HashMap<String, String>,
    user_ops: &'a HashMap<String, String>,
) -> std::result::Result<Vec<&'a str>, Error> {
    if symbols.iter().all(|x| ops.get(x.as_ref()).is_some()) {
        let symbols = symbols.iter().map(|x| x.as_ref()).collect();
        return Ok(symbols);
    }

    let mut expanded: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    for s in symbols {
        let s = s.as_ref();
        if ops.contains_key(s) || s.parse::<i32>().is_ok() {
            expanded.push(s);
        } else {
            let mut resolved = user_ops
                .get(s)
                .ok_or(Error::Bad)?
                .split_ascii_whitespace()
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            expanded.append(&mut resolved);
        }
    }
    expand_symbols(&expanded, ops, user_ops)
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `expanded`
  --> src/main.rs:32:5
   |
32 |     expand_symbols(&expanded, ops, user_ops)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |              |
   |     |              `expanded` is borrowed here
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

However, if I change the last statement to:

```
Ok(expanded)
```

it works, but it's not longer recursive.

I understand the idea that I'm trying to return a value borrowed from a local frame, but I think this is safe based on the second example. How can I tell the compiler that?

Note: I'm using `AsRef` because I want to be able to pass both a `Vec<String>` and `Vec<&str>` to `expand_symbols()`. Maybe I need to forget about that?

Comment: I see `'a` in three places: two arguments and a return value. Do you really want all three of those lifetimes to be the *same*? Is there a reason in your algorithm that they have to be?

Comment: No but the compiler told me too. :) I believe because elements from both `symbols` and `user_ops` can end up in the return value.

Answer (score 1):

With `Ok(expanded)` the variable `expanded` is moved out of the function, meaning no reference to it existing after the function returned. So, the second sample, if you meant by `Ok(expanded)`, is not same as the original one.

To address the issue I think you can pass a mutable reference to `symbols` as the first parameter of the function, and do in-place edit on it instead of creating a new local vector, `explanded`.

```
fn expand_symbols<'a>(
    symbols: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>,
    ops: &HashMap<String, String>,
    user_ops: &'a HashMap<String, String>,
) -> std::result::Result<&'a Vec<&'a str>, Error> {
    if symbols.is_empty() || symbols.iter().all(|x| ops.get(*x).is_some()) {
         return Ok(symbols);
    }

    let mut unresolved: Vec<&str> = vec![]; 
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < symbols.len() {
        let s = symbols[i];
        if ops.contains_key(s) || s.parse::<i32>().is_ok() {
            i += 1;
        } else {
            unresolved.push(symbols.remove(i));
        }
    }

    for s in unresolved.iter() {
        let mut resolved = user_ops
            .get(*s)
            .ok_or(Error::Bad)?
            .split_ascii_whitespace()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        symbols.append(&mut resolved);
    };

    expand_symbols(symbols, ops, user_ops)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53d2a92fc9d26bd949f3b64525989257)